# How to split an HTML string into chunks in PHP?

Tags: php, substring

I would like to split a string efficiently into different sub strings  like this :

```
  <li><a href="">One</a></li><li><a href>Two</a></li><li><a href>Three</a></li>.....<li><a herf>Last</a></li>
```

I would like to split this string in 3 parts and put each string in a variable.

The first variable $first should contain the first li (`<li>One</li>`)
The second variable $second should contain the rest expect the last (`<li>Two</li><li>Three</li>.....`)
The third variable $third should contain the last li (`<li>Last</li>`)

Anyone can help ?

Comment: $begining_tree = strstr($variable, '</li>', true); $end_tree = strstr($variables, '</li>');

Comment: And it is exactly like that? With only those tags?

Comment: Your input string clearly is HTML, so why not treat it as such: Parse the markup (PHP comes with `DOMDocument` as a builtin parser), and iterate over the `li` nodes

Comment: exctly like that with those tags

Comment: `DOMDocument` will also give you a handy `DOMNOde` object which has the attributes `->firstChild` and `->lastChild`  - so you could then just pull the child nodes and extract the first and last children to give you your 3 vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work:

```
<?php 

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<li><a href="#">One</a></li><li><a href="#">Two</a></li><li><a href="#">Three</a></li><li><a href="#">Last</a></li>');
$liTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');

$chunks = array();
foreach ($liTags as $li) {
    $chunks[] = '<li>'.strip_tags($li->nodeValue).'</li>';
}

list($first,$second,$third) = array(
   array_slice($chunks,0,1),
   array_slice($chunks,1,count($chunks)-2),
   array_slice($chunks,-1),    
);


?>
```

Comment: Thanks,  
I have edited my question to include a tag I omitted (<a>). This method above would not work , any idea ? –

Comment: I edited my code, try now

Comment: This is an awesome solution. TX

Comment: insteda of `strip_tag($li->nodeValue)`, as per documentation of the `DOMNode` class (cf my answer): `$li->textContent` will work equally well, if not better

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do here, because you're dealing with markup, is to treat the data as what it is: HTML. Parse the DOM tree, iterate over the nodes you're interested in and get the data like so:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($data);//parses the markup string
$li = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
$liValues = [];
foreach ($li as $elem) {
    $liValues[] = $elem->textContent; // not nodeValue if the nodes can contain other elements, like in your case an "a" tag
}
```

To get the first, last and middle elements, just write this:

```
$length = $li->length; // or count($li); to get the total number of li's
$nodes = [
    $li->item(0), //first
    $li->item(round($length/2)), // middle
    $li->item($length -1), // last
];
//or, given that you don't need the actual nodes
$nodes = [
    $li->item(0)->textContent,
    $li->item(round($length/2))->textContent,
    $li->item($length -1)->textContent,
];
```

Or just get the parent node (`ul` or `ol`), and use `$parent->firstChild` and `$parent->lastChild` to get the first and last elements in the list, as CD001 suggested in the comments.

Useful links:

- http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

You can use the [`attributes` property](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes) of the `DOMNode` elements in the `DOMNodeList` returned by `getElementsByTagName` to further exapand on the data you store

Comment: This helps me by using array_shift and array_pop on liValues. I dont need the nodes array. Also the lenght of of $li can not be obtained by count($li) but with $li->lenght since $li is a dom object NOW. Thank you

Comment: I have edited my question to include a tag I omitted (<a>). This method above would not work , any idea ?

Comment: @Mamadou: replace `$elem->nodeValue` with `$elem->textContent` as documented in the second link in my answer: `textContent` is the text within a node _and its descendants_. Meaning that `<li><a href='#'>foo</a> bar</li>` has a text content: `foo bar`. Updated my answer

Comment: @Mamadou: `count($li)` ***should*** work, given that the `DomNodeList` return value implements the `Traversable` interface (so the object supports array access, `foreach` iteration, and `count`)

Answer (score -2):

you can try with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

see code example:

```
<?php
// Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

// Example 2
$data = "foo:*:1023:1000::/home/foo:/bin/sh";
list($user, $pass, $uid, $gid, $gecos, $home, $shell) = explode(":", $data);
echo $user; // foo
echo $pass; // *

?>
```

Comment: But this example is not what OP is looking for?

Comment: not this, i have a fixed string send by an API for some purpuse I need to extract the first li , the middle of the chain and the last li