# Remove all except inside tag

Tags: php, strip

How to remove all from page except text inside `<p>` tag?

Page:

```html
  This is text.
  <div class="text">This is text in 'div' tag</div>
  <p>This is text in 'p' tag</p>
```

Expected result:

> This is text in 'p' tag

Greetings.

Comment: Can you give more information about what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'll have to parse the markup. PHP comes with a good parser in the form of [the `DOMDocument` class](http://php.net/DOMDocument), so that's really quite easy:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
```

Next, get all `p` tags:

```
$paragraphs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
```

This method returns a `DOMNodeList` object, which implements the `Traversable` interface, so you can use it as an array of `DOMNode` instances (`DOMElement` in this case):

```
$first = $paragraphs->item(0);//or $paragraphs[0] even
foreach ($paragraphs as $p) {
    echo $p->textContent;//echo the inner text
}
```

If you only want the paragraph elements that *do not contain child elements*, then you can easily check that:

```
foreach ($paragraphs as $p) {
    if (!$p->hasChildNodes()) {
        echo $p->textContent; // or $p->nodeValue
    }
}
```

A closely related answer with some more links/info: [How to split an HTML string into chunks in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076511/how-to-split-an-html-string-into-chunks-in-php/39076776#39076776)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with the *native php strip_tags* function like so:

```
strip_tags("<p>This is text in 'p' tag</p>");
```

Which will return as you expected, "This is text in 'p' tag". **NOTE:** this is only *useful* when you have an *outer-container div*, and you use a little bit of *dirty RegExp* in order to strip not only the P, but the whole tags the user expected (ex. the div tag). This function has one argument, and a second optional argument. The first one is the string that you are stripping the tags from, and the second one *specifies allowable tags* that won't be *stripped* as a **string**. These tags will not be removed in the process. For more information on the strip_tags function click [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp)

I hope you got the idea :)

Comment: You're not addressing the first part of the question: how to extract the `p` tags from the string. There's a div tag in the OP's example code, for example. How would you process those?

Comment: Like this: strip_tags("<div class="text">This is text in 'div' tag</div>")->replace('class="text"', "");

Comment: My point still stands: how do you extract the `div` string from the source string? You simply can't do that without parsing the DOM. Markup needs to be parsed in order for you to work out where the `p` tags sit, whether or not there are tags _inside_ that paragraph tag, and process them correctly. Your answer assumes, more or less, the input string will always be in the format: _"<opening tag>text contents</closing tag>"_, which is, clearly, isn't the case. BTW: `strip_tags($string)->replace("attribute='value'", '');` is invalid syntax, and pointless, strip tags will clear the attributes too

Comment: Good point. I didn't completely understand what you meant in my previous comment. But it works on some occasions when the user has a container div, and uses a bit of dirty RegExp. BTW, sorry about the misguided replace. It should be `str_replace(find,replace,string,count)`, right?

Comment: Not quite: Regex and markup don't work, as _"explained"_ in this classic SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1230836

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the link! So, for the most efficient and correct answer as expected, you have to use the DOMDocument class and parse the DOM. Although,  even when parsing the DOM, instead of using `$node -> textContent`, it is possible to use the `strip_tags(string, count)` function. As seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076511/how-to-split-an-html-string-into-chunks-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, `strip_tags` will work on `nodeValue`, but why bother calling an extra function, if the `DOMNode` already contains the text content without tags under `$node->textContent` in the first place?